# Return value -1 not printing

Tags: python, return

```
def palindrome(text):
    lenText = len(text)

    if text == "":
        print("Success")
        return 1

    else:
        print(text[0])
        print(text[lenText - 1])

        if text[0] == text[lenText - 1]:
            palindrome(text[1:lenText - 1])

        else:
            return -1


print(palindrome("tesseet"))
```

why does the -1 or 1 not get printed after bring returned and exited? Am i not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Check out a visual debugger like [pythontutor](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit) and step through your code.

Comment: because the text that you have entered does not equal "" to return 1 ,